# add title using grid.arrange for multiple plots made with gridExtra::grid.arrange

Tags: grid, gridextra

I have to use gridExtra::grid.arrange for plotting several plot besides eachother because of the package I am using to create the fit for the plot.
I have to create a title for the plot using grid.arrange. 
Now I want to combine the two, but cannot figure out how. So: I want to plot several figures besides eachother and give them all have a different title.

I have euler1 and euler2 as fits tat represent my data in an euler diagram. 
for plotting 2 plots besides eachother this code works for me:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot(euler1),plot(euler2))
```

for giving a single plot a title, this code works for me:

```
plot1 <- plot(euler1)
grid.arrange(grobs = list(plot1), top = "Title 1")
```

Now, I would like to combine the two codes.
How can I do it?

I tries for example (but doesn't work):

```
plot1 <- plot(euler1)
plot2 <- plot(euler2)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, grobs = list(plot1, plot2), top = list("Title 1","Title 2"))
```

Kinds regards,
Judith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, since the use of `main` in `plot` was fixed for the eulerr package. Now I can use:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot(euler1, main = 'title1'),
plot(euler2, main = 'title2'))
```

Thanks everyone for the feedback.

Answer (score 10):

Typically you'd add titles to the plot themselves, as in

```
p1 = ggplot() + ggtitle('plot 1')
p2 = ggplot() + ggtitle('plot 2')

grid.arrange(grobs = list(p1, p2), top = "Global Title", ncol=2)
```

but if you prefer to use grid.arrange's `top` argument for the titles, you can nest them,

```
p = ggplot()
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p, top = 'title 1'), arrangeGrob(p, top = 'title 2'), top = "Global Title", ncol=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. unfortunately the package I am using (eulerr) depends on its own custom plot implementation for which ggplot is not an option, therefore I have to use the syntax stated in my original question 'plot' and 'grid.arrange' with 'top', and 'gridExtra'.